# What is considered a grammatical case in the framework of turkic languages?

Tags: grammar, cases, turkic-languages

Let's take kazakh language as an example. In every source I've read there are 7 cases in kazakh language:

1. nominative **üi** - a house, **baqşa** - garden;
2. genitive **üi-diŋ** - of a house, **baqşa-niŋ** - of a garden;
3. dative **üi-ge** - (in)to a house, **baqşa-ğa** - to a garden;
4. accusative **üi-di** - a house, **baqşa-ni** - a garden;
5. locative **üi-de** - in a house, **baqşa-da** - in a garden;
6. ablative **üi-den** - from a house, **baqşa-dan** - from a garden;
7. instrumental **üi-men** - with a house, **baqşa-men** - with a garden.

But I could distinguish at least 3 more cases:

8. abessive **üi-siz** - without a house, **baqşa-siz** - without a garden
9. essive **üi-she** - as a house, **baqşa-sha** - as a garden
10. comparative **üi-dei** - like a house, **baqşa-dai** - like a garden

Are these 3 more can be considered as grammatical cases?

Update:

There are similar cases in turkish language:

*İlgisizlik Hali* (abessive) **bahçe-siz** "without garden"

*Eşitlik Hali* (essive) **bahçe-ce** "as a garden"

Comment: No, because those change the part of speech (eg from noun to adjective).

Comment: It's nothing unique to Turkic by the way, it's just like English *-less*.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer can you back up your first statement with a source?

Comment: Why isn't *-luk* or *-ki* as in *evdeki* a case ending?

Comment: *İlgisizlik Hali* is not considered as a case in Turkish. It is a derivational suffix. Hence if you use it, you create a new word (has a place in a dictionary)

Comment: It's also worth noting that 8-10 are entirely productive.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer, while 8-10 all have attributive readings, they also all have adverbial readings (not to mention potential substantive readings).  Many of the other cases have adverbial readings—which makes me wonder about the basis of your argument.  Why can't a noun case change the grammatical function of the noun?  (And how do you distinguish that from deriving a new word with a different part of speech?)

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Cases like the abessive and essive, also change the functional part of speech of nouns in Uralic languages, but they’re still considered cases. Declined case forms of nouns act as other parts of speech in many languages. What is and isn’t considered a case in a given language is largely down to convention.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That may be the answer.

Comment: @JonathanW. Yeah, the main cause of my original question was that I once saw how many cases uralic languages (finnish, hungarian) have and asked myself if turkic languages are very similar in structure why we have only 6-7 cases.

Comment: @Tuňuquq, part of the answer to that question is the linguists working on the languages.  It's also very hard to draw a principled line between cases and postposition.  E.g., in Kazakh, -Men(en) functions almost identically to Kyrgyz мен(ен) in all ways, but in Kazakh it's written together (when not used in a conjunction-like way) and is considered a case suffix, whereas in Kyrgyz it's written separately and considered a postposition.  All solely based on convention.  The real question is "how can 'case affix' be defined in a cross-linguistic way?"  The answer is probably that it can't be.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER: I'm not a linguist and I don't have an authoritative source to back my reasoning, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

[Grammatical case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_case) reflects the grammatical function performed by a word in a phrase, clause or sentence. Noun in a given case (e.g. *úi-ge*) remains a noun and retains its meaning.

That gives us multiple good reasons to not treat the word-forming suffixes, like *-siz*, as additional grammatical cases:

- suffix doesn't reflect the grammatical function of a word in a sentence;
- suffix changes the part of speech, *úi-siz* becomes an adjective (as @AdamBittlingmayer said in the comments);
- suffix creates a new word, with a new meaning (as @kabraxis said in the comments);
- this new word, can have a grammatical case of its own:

  1. nominative *úi-siz* - homeless
  2. genitive *úı-siz-diń* - of homeless
  3. dative *úı-siz-ge* - to homeless
  4. accusative *úı-siz-di* - homeless
  5. locative *úı-siz-de* - by (at?) homeless
  6. ablative *úı-siz-den* - from homeless
  7. instrumental *úı-siz-ben* - with homeless
- suffixes can be combined multiple times, creating new words: *úi-siz-dei* - like a homeless, *úi-siz-der-siz* - without homeless.

It's much more convenient to treat *úi-siz* as a new word than a case of *úi*.

Comment: Consider this sentence: Men sensiz ómir súre almaımyn. I cannot live without you. Here suffix -siz doesn't produce an adjective.

Comment: Also it doesn't produce a new word but rather denotes a lack of the given noun. In this case **you**.

Comment: @Tuňuquq This is an interesting example. I suggest editing it into your question, it will certainly benefit from usage examples. You can actually build a similar example with úi-siz: *men úısiz qaldym* (I was left without a home).

Comment: @Tuňuquq Now, when I see where you're coming from your question looks much more interesting to me. Indeed, the lines between declension and word formation become murky here. Still, I'm not entirely convinced that *sensiz* isn't a new word. It serves as a modifier to *ómir* (you-less life, so to speak) answers the question "how?" (qalaı?) and can be replaced with an adverb: *Men bylaı ómir súre almaımyn* (I can't live a life this way). Actually, [some sources](https://bit.ly/327BaCg) put both -sha and -siz as adverb-generating suffixes.

Comment: @defaultlocale, I don't see it as modifying _ómir_ here, but as being adverbial to the verb (_ómir_) _súr-_.  In principle it could be ambiguous here, but there are definitely examples where it couldn't be considered attributive in any way.  Maybe something like _ol jerge sensiz bara almaımyn_ (I can't go there without you).